# Hotellings T2 in R

Tags: r, statistics, t-test, multivariate-testing

I am trying too use the Hotellings T2 test in r too compare two vectors. Will the hotellings t2 test automatically calculated the mean of the 2 vectors I am comparing or will I have too do it myself?
Many thanks
The function I am using is
ICSNP::HotellingsT2

Comment: Hi Conor, at the very least, please provide the name of the function you are trying to use. Function documentation might also be a good place to check out, you can get to it by calling `?my_function` or `help("my_function")`.

Comment: Apologies I am using the ICSNP HotellingsT2 function

Comment: Looking at the function documentation, mean is not listed amongst the the output values. I recommend trying to run the function and then inspecting the output yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

The `ICSNP::HotellingsT2()` function returns an object of type `htest()`,  a list of seven items, none of which are means for the objects being compared. We can validate this by using the function to compare average `mpg` in the `mtcars` data frame by transmission type (manual or automatic).

```
library(ICSNP)
aResult <- HotellingsT2(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$am)
str(aResult)
```

...and the result:

```
> str(aResult)
List of 7
 $ statistic  : num [1, 1] 16.9
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "T.2"
 $ p.value    : num [1, 1] 0.000285
 $ method     : chr "Hotelling's two sample T2-test"
 $ parameter  : Named num [1:2] 1 30
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "df1" "df2"
 $ data.name  : chr "mtcars$mpg by mtcars$am"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ null.value : Named chr "c(0)"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "location difference"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

You can calculate the means by group with `base::aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(mpg ~ am,data = mtcars,mean)

> aggregate(mpg ~ am,data = mtcars,mean)
  am      mpg
1  0 17.14737
2  1 24.39231
```